# can i get one record for this query . SELECT count(adate),a1 FROM ts025 Group by a1 .a1 is boolean value

Tags: sql, postgresql

In mytable I have "A1" boolean type and "adate" Date type.
when i run `SELECT count(adate),a1 FROM ts025 Group by a1.` it show me two record for a1 true and a1 false condition. 
In this condition i just want one record. like count(adate ) and True.
Is there anyone can help me!!
Thanks,

```
mytable  |A1     |adate     |                A1    |adate
           true  |2013-01-1 |                false  |2013-01-1 |
           false |2013-01-2 |                false  |2013-01-2 |
```

In this case i want

```
               count  | a1            In this case i want   count  | a1
                    2 | true                                     2 | false
```

*If one record is true, it should comeout true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT count(adate), bool_or(a1) 
FROM ts025
```

The aggregate `bool_or` will return

> true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false

More aggregate functions here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html